# NPAPI plugin not being invoked always

Tags: c, networking, browser, http-headers, npapi

I have written NPAPI plugin using firebreath. It works fine for all the registered mime-types. The plugin is registered for video/x-flv also. Now, whenever i type a url in address bar whose response contains video/x-flv content type, my plugin is invoked and it handles the response. But i observed, that when we play any flash video in browser, suppose in youtube, firefox sends many requests whose response contain video/x-flv as content type, but my plugin is not invoked. Why those requests remain transparent to my plugin? Same thing can be observed for vlc web plugin, which is also registered for video/x-flv content type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<object>` tags for Flash videos have type `application/x-shockwave-flash`, which Flash handles and your plugin doesn't. If the Flash plugin itself requests sub-resources, those won't in turn invoke plugins (what would that even do?); NPAPI isn't intended as a generic way to intercept network traffic.

Comment: Your answer sounds perfectly logical. Most probably the requests are sent by flash plugin, which any plugin can do easily!

Comment: I tried to play video through HTML5 in firefox, this time also plugin wasn't invoked!

Comment: Plugins are only invoked if there isn't something else handling it; if the file is requested by another plugin (like flash) or if it's being handled by something else (like a video or audio tag) you won't see it